# How to group by continuous time periods and sum a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

```
id| startdate | enddate | team | score
1| 2011-09-25 | 2012-03-31 | blue | 380
1| 2012-04-01 | 2012-07-31 | blue | 147
1| 2012-08-01 | 2013-01-31 | green| 217
1| 2013-02-01 | 2015-02-28 | green| 1540
1| 2015-03-01 | 2015-09-30 | green| 300
1| 2015-10-01 | 2018-04-30 | blue | 2193
1| 2018-05-01 | 2020-12-31 | blue | 1743
1| 2023-05-01 | 2023-09-30 | blue | 159
1| 2023-10-01 | 9999-12-31 | green| *
```

I need to merge the continuous time periods in this view where the team is the same and add the scores to get that team's total score in that period. 
Note that, the value for the last time frame is * because it is the current time frame, and the value is only inserted after the time period is finished. Also, all the values for the score are in *string format* not integer format.

Expected output:

```
id| startdate| enddate| team| score
1| 2011-09-25| 2012-07-31| blue|  527
1| 2012-08-01| 2015-09-30| green| 2057
1| 2015-10-01| 2020-12-31| blue| 3963
1| 2023-05-01| 2023-09-30| blue| 159
1| 2023-10-01| 9999-12-31| green| *
```

Comment: You have a typos in the dates values, (2015-02-31, 2018-04-31).

Comment: For the blue team, from 2015-10-01 to 2023-09-30 why the result is two rows, I think it should be one row with a sum value of 4095, is that correct?

Comment: @Ahmed Sorry for the typos, also for the 2015-10-01 to 2023-09-30 timeframe, they should be different, because after 2020-12-31 there are no entries for that id till 2023-05-01. The merged time frames should be without breaks / continuous. Maybe it could be that the player took a break or did not find any team in that period. Basically, the new start date should be last end date + 1 for it to be considered continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, you may try the following using `ROW_NUMBER` function to define groups for the consecutive teams, then using `DATEDIFF` define another groups within a team to check if there is break in the dates.

```
WITH grps AS
  (
  SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) - 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, team ORDER BY startdate) grp
  FROM table_name
  )
SELECT id, MIN(startdate) startdate, MAX(enddate) enddate, team, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(score) = '*' 
            THEN '*'
            ELSE SUM(score) 
       END AS score
FROM
  (
    SELECT *, COALESCE(DATEDIFF(startdate, LAG(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY enddate)), 1) grp2
    FROM grps
  ) T
GROUP BY id, team, grp, grp2 
ORDER BY id, startdate
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_BxPxBM1).

Comment: Works wonders! ty